# django admin lost password recovery

Tags: django, django-admin

I have some data in my dev database (not yest exported to fixtures), so I dont want to run syncdb.

However, I have lost my pwd for the admin section of my demo django website (I have not worked on it for a little while)

Is the password stored somewhere in the config/settings etc?

How can I recover the admin pwd?

Comment: I have since remembered the pwd and gained access. BUT this is still useful info to know fro the future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have Django 1.2 installed, you can simply invoke `./manage.py changepassword <username>`.

If your version of Django is older, you could change the password in Django's interactive shell:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u = User.objects.get(username='<username>')
>>> u.set_password('<password>')
>>> u.save()
```